# How to combine two rotations at two different anchor points to transform UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, rotation, transformation

I would like to rotate my UIView firstly around its left edge and secondly around its right edge. The first rotation should produce a door opening effect and once finished the second rotation should start. When also the second rotation finishes the effect should be as if the view was pushed down in the z-plane. The transformation is part of a manual animation and of course should be seamlessly.

[image: two consecutive rotations around two different points]

By intuition I guess it is not possible to use anchor points and to concatenate 2 rotations that take place at different anchor points (but if I'm wrong please correct me). Hence instead of using anchor points I'm using matrix combination to produce the effect of "rotating at".

The first rotation is quite easy but I do not know how to append the second one. Perhaps before applying the second rotation I should move by translation toward right on the y-coord and down in the z-coord (with something like cos(90 - angle) * view.width) to reach the position of the right edge at the end of the first rotation. However attempts I did were not successful. Any idea?
Here is what I have so far for the first rotation:

```
-(void) transform:(float) percentage{

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;

    //here I get the angle for the 1st rotation (percentage 0 -> angle 0; percentage 0.5 -> angle 45°
    float angle = [self getFirstRotationAngle: percentage];
    CATransform3D translateToRotateAt = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(myView.frame.size.width / 2.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    CATransform3D rotation1 = CATransform3DIdentity;
    rotation1.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
    rotation1 = CATransform3DRotate(rotation1, angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    CATransform3D translateBackToRotateAt = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-myView.frame.size.width / 2.0, 0.0, 0.0f);

    transform = CATransform3DConcat(translateToRotateAt, rotation1);
    transform = CATransform3DConcat(transform , translateBackToRotateAt);

    if (percentage > 0.5){
        angle = [self getSecondRotationAngle: percentage];

        // here I should get the second part of the transformation and concatenate it to the first part
    }

    myView.layer.transform = transform;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this method can make a transform for you which with your degree that gives to its

```
func makeTransform(horizontalDegree: CGFloat, verticalDegree: CGFloat, maxVertical: CGFloat,rotateDegree: CGFloat, maxHorizontal: CGFloat) -> CATransform3D {
    var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
           
    transform.m34 = 1 / -500
    
    let xAnchor = (horizontalDegree / (2 * maxHorizontal)) + 0.5
    let yAnchor = (verticalDegree / (-2 * maxVertical)) + 0.5
    let anchor = CGPoint(x: xAnchor, y: yAnchor)
    
    setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: anchor, forView: self.imgView)
    let hDegree  = (CGFloat(horizontalDegree) * .pi)  / 180
    let vDegree  = (CGFloat(verticalDegree) * .pi)  / 180
    let rDegree  = (CGFloat(rotateDegree) * .pi)  / 180
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, vDegree , 1, 0, 0)
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, hDegree , 0, 1, 0)
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, rDegree , 0, 0, 1)
    
    return transform
}

func setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: CGPoint, forView view: UIView) {
    var newPoint = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width * anchorPoint.x, y: view.bounds.size.height * anchorPoint.y)
    var oldPoint = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width * view.layer.anchorPoint.x, y: view.bounds.size.height * view.layer.anchorPoint.y)
    
    newPoint = newPoint.applying(view.transform)
    oldPoint = oldPoint.applying(view.transform)
    
    var position = view.layer.position
    position.x -= oldPoint.x
    position.x += newPoint.x
    
    position.y -= oldPoint.y
    position.y += newPoint.y
    
    print("Anchor: \(anchorPoint)")
    
    view.layer.position = position
    view.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint
}
```